# I have deleted my downvoted questions and answers, but there's no change in my reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-posts

I was just wondering why my reputation hasn't changed after I deleted two downvoted answers and one downvoted question.

Comment: Just fyi meta up votes won't bring you reputation ;)

Comment: You should note that it takes some time for lost reputation to be recovered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see of your reputation, you do appear to have recovered the losses incurred from downvoting.

With the baptism/christening question, your [November 22 answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/359611/18696) and your [November 23 answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/359751/18696) have both had their reputation penalties restored.

Your ["exact origin of the English language"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360099/what-is-the-exact-origin-of-the-english-language) question resulted in a net movement of reputation of zero on November 25.

We don't normally post screenshots of what moderators see, so I don't particularly want to do that. But I can't see any error in the way the system has handled the reputation calculations here. It is a stable, robust and tested mechanism.

This is the time, though, to restate a warning about deleting badly-received posts. **They still count in the automatic quality check.** Rather than removing posts, you should attempt to improve them. With off-topic questions, it can be difficult to make them on-topic, so you need to be sure to post on-topic questions in the first place (but you removed your question without the community deciding it was off-topic). There is a question on MSE, the network-wide meta.stackexchange, about the [post bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) which can result from too many low-quality posts: deleting them only makes it more difficult to recover the situation because they remain low-quality.

I can't tell whether you're in any danger of triggering the post ban: I don't know what its criteria are; it's automatic and it just happens. You may be OK at the moment. But if you try and model your questions and answers on upvoted posts by high-rep users, you may receive more upvotes and find that you feel fewer deletions are necessary.